Saving a get-parameter in Node.js
Guys stitch in the button to open a webapp (a regular website that allows you to interact with Telegram) Telegram URL with the parameter /?code=123123123. I need to catch this parameter in Node.js Express and send it to the frontend, so I can send this parameter with a get request.
But I can't do that. I can see the request URL data if the backend is running without express.static(...) middleware. But I can't get the data when I include express.static(...) in the code. It turns out I either see the value or the frontend. And I need to run the frontend part and catch the parameter at the same time.
Nginx:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.com ;
    root /var/www/crop-image-frontend;
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

Node.js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;

  fs.writeFile('file.txt', code, (err) => {
    if (err) console.error('Error writing to file:', err);
   
    res.send('Value saved to file');
  });
});

It works fine that way. The value appears in the file. But as soon as I turn on app.use('/api', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'path to frontend'))); the value stops being written to the file.

When you add express.static middleware to serve static files from a directory and route it with app.use('/api', express.static(...)), it essentially takes precedence over your dynamic route handler for GET /api. This is because Express evaluates middleware in the order they are added. When a request matches the path prefix used in app.use(), Express will attempt to serve a static file corresponding to the remainder of the URL. If a file is not found, depending on your configuration, it might not automatically pass control to the next route handler (in your case, the dynamic handler for GET /api), especially if the static middleware ends the response cycle or a file like api/index.html is found and served.
The simplest solution is to avoid overlap between your API routes and the routes serving static files. For instance, you could serve your API under /api and static files from another route that does not overlap, like /static or / for the frontend. This way, there is a clear distinction between API calls and requests for static assets.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'path to frontend where you have your static files')));
app.use('/api', bodyParser.json()); // Make sure bodyParser.json() is scoped to your API routes if all of them need JSON parsing

